# Erro de Exceção Flutter em firebase_auth

Tags: firebase, flutter, auth

Boa tarde,
Estou usando o plugin do firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1 para autenticar usuário.

Quando o usuário corresponde as informações de login nenhum erro é mostrado, porem quando o usuario esta incorreto e uma exceção é gerada, o flutter não consegue capturar o codigo da exceção.

```
    class UserManager {
  // config FIREBASE
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  ///
  ////sigin
  Future<void> fazerLogin(
      {Usuario usuario, Function onFail, Function onSuccess}) async {
    // resultado a auteticação
    try {
      final UserCredential result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: usuario.email,
        password: usuario.senha,
      );
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      onFail(getErrorString(e.code));
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Figura da Exceção]

segue as informações do console

```
W/System  ( 8621): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/flutter ( 8621): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/wrong-password] The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
E/flutter ( 8621): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword
package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:497
E/flutter ( 8621): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Quer saber como tratar para que o Flutter "entenda" a exceção de "Senha incorreta?" e execute o `try-catch`? Não ficou muito claro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `firebase_auth` lança uma `FirebaseAuthException`, conforme explícito na própria [documentação](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html):

> A FirebaseAuthException maybe thrown with the following error code:

Então você precisa capturar uma `FirebaseAuthException` e não uma `PlatformException`  e tratar de acordo com o código de erro.

Ex:

```dart
Future<void> logInWithEmailAndPassword({
    @required String email,
    @required String password,
}) async {
  try {
    await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e, s) {
    _handleFirebaseLoginWithCredentialsException(e, s);
  } on Exception catch (e, s) {
    //Outro problema
  }
}

void _handleFirebaseLoginWithCredentialsException(
    FirebaseAuthException e, StackTrace s) {
  if (e.code == 'user-disabled') {
    //'O usuário informado está desabilitado.'
  } else if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    //'O usuário informado não está cadastrado.'
  } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
    //'O domínio do e-mail informado é inválido.'
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    //'A senha informada está incorreta.'
  } else {
    //Outro problema
  }
}
```

Comment: Olá, com esse código a exceção é capturada, porem um crash é gerado. Então a única opção foi desabilitar o crash do vs code.

Muito obrigado amigo !

Comment: @PabloOliveira se a resposta lhe auxiliou, você pode marcá-la como correta. :)